# Extending a general purpose function

Tags: c++, design-patterns, enums

I'm creating a game, and in this game a ball can be caught in various ways, which all result in different behaviour. Initially, I wanted to add an enum to a certain general purpose method when catching to ball, which will then delegate the actions that take place when a ball gets caught in a certain way. An example would be:

```
void Weapon::Catch(Character Catcher, CatchMethod Method)
{
    switch (Method)
    {
        case Method::PickUp: OnPickup(Catcher); break;
        case Method::Pass:   OnPass(Catcher);  break;
        // etc
    }
}
```

This would allow me to call the function as:

```
MyWeapon->Catch(Catcher, Method::Pickup);
MyWeapon->Catch(Catcher, Method::Pass);
```

and the likes. I think this would read nicer than

```
MyWeapon->CatchByPickup(Catcher);
MyWeapon->CatchByPass(Catcher);
```

My main issue however, is that this is not extendable at all, which is what I was actually hoping to achieve with this general purpose method. If I make the method an enum, I cannot simply extend the enum and override the virtual `Catch` method in a derived class of `Weapon`. If I decide to extend the method in some derived class, I'd have to create a new enum which begins at the last value of the `Method` enum. I do not feel that this is a proper way to deal with the situation, but I do not know what the best practise in this case would be. Does it perhaps involve template specializations? The main problem to me, is that I cannot simply extend enums.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what the utility is on a 'general method' whose valid inputs could vary in a derived class. Would not the whole point of having `CatchMethod` be that all possible variations of `Catch` be expressed in it, and it's up to the `Weapon` classes to properly handle them? Basically, if I have to know the concrete type of `Weapon` I'm dealthing with in order to know what type of catching I can perform, then there's really no reason not to have each catch method spelled out explisitly in the API as seprate method calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of `std::function`.

```
using CatchMethod = std::function<void(Character)>;

void Weapon::Catch(Character Catcher, CatchMethod Method)
{
  Method(Catcher);
}
```

Calling the function is then pretty straightforward

```
// If its a regular function you can just use the pointer to the function
weapon.Catch(Player, &OnPickup);
// If its a member function you can use lambda
weapon.Catch(Player, [this](Character Catcher){OnPickup(Catcher);});
// or std::bind (slightly more verbose and less flexible)
weapon.Catch(Player, std::bind(&Weapon::OnPickup, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: This allows me to use the same method, which will do some standard stuff that always has to be done, as well as calling a custom method where needed. It's a bit verbose, but would do exactly as I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit non-obvious since I'm not sure if you have any other code in your `Catch` method that is relevant to the system, but it sounds to me like you would want to simply not use methods at all and invert the control to have different functions. Like this, for example:

```
void pickup(Weapon weapon, Character catcher) {
    /* Do whatever your OnPickup does */
}

void pass(Weapon weapon, Character catcher) {
    /* Do whatever your OnPass does */
}
```

And then, obviously, just call them like this:

```
pickup(MyWeapon, Catcher);
pass(MyWeapon, Catcher);
```

If there is no surrounding code or similar prerequisites that you don't show in the question, I don't think there are any back sides to this, and declaring new functions to do similar things is entirely decentralized and extensible.

If it is that you need to pass the `CatchMethod` through other functions, you could simply pass a function pointer instead.

As an aside, by the way, unless `Weapon` and `Character` here are typedefs to something else, it's generally a bad idea to pass these kinds of things by-value. You probably want to use references or pointers instead.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that how `pickup` or `pass` would be implemented could vary from `Weapon` to `Weapon`. But certainly your overall point that, as described, it doesn't seem like the OP gains anything from the enum+general method form as described is valid.

Comment: @aruisdante: Perhaps, but in that case he'd need to have methods for those in the weapon anyway and wouldn't have anything to gain from the enum system, as far as I can tell (much as you say).

Comment: Exactly, I agree with you completely. As currently described, the Enum is simply serving as a way to select which method is actually called in the `Weapon` class. It's just transforming `Weapon.XY(Catcher)` to `Weapon.X(Catcher, Y)`, which has debatable utility to the given use-case.

Comment: Indeed. I guess I based my answer on the assumption that OP's goal was to decentralize the definition of new catching methods so that they didn't all have to be declared in one place, which this solves. If the goal is something else, then OP can please explain what.